# How can I use data validation in Google Sheets to keep two or more characters from being put in a cell?

Tags: validation, google-sheets, url, utm

We have a google sheet UTM builder for our tracking URLs. One use case we've run into recently is some users are inputting reserved characters (like '?' or '&') into UTM values, causing trouble in the final URL string.

Google sheets does have data validation on a cell for 'text does not contain', but it appears to only apply to one value at a time, per cell. Is there a way to exclude a list of values without making it a dropdown?

Attempted to use data validation in Google sheets in various ways.

Answer (score 0):

result of data validation (or conditional formatting) needs to be always boolean (TRUE / FALSE) therefore try custom formula:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1; "[?&]")
```

[image]